# SQL Null as 0 with Left Join?

Tags: mysql, sql

#### Problem

I have a logs table where users enter how many hours they spent on a project. (It's used for graphs and data tables on the application). I also generated a "calendar" table so I can left join dates, and fill the "empty" dates with zero. However, after spending some time, I couldn't find a way to do it...

#### Table 1 : Logs

```
id | hoursSpent | logDate 
1    5            2018-08-05
2    1            2018-08-07
3    3            2018-08-10
```

#### Table 2 : Calendar

```
id         | db_date
20180807     2018-08-07
20180808     2018-08-08
20180809     2018-08-09
201808010    2018-08-10
etc...
```

#### Desired Output

```
db_date      | hoursSpent
2018-08-05     5
2018-08-06     0
2018-08-07     1
2018-08-08     0
2018-08-09     0
2018-08-10     3
```

#### Code Used So Far (Doesn't work exactly...)

```
SELECT hoursSpent, db_date
FROM logs LEFT JOIN calendar ON db_date
WHERE db_date BETWEEN '2018-08-10' AND '2018-08-01'
GROUP BY db_date
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of `LEFT JOIN` is correct.  The rest of the query needs cleaning up:

```
SELECT c.db_date, COALESCE(l.hoursSpent, 0) as hoursSpent
FROM calendar c LEFT JOIN
     logs l
     ON c.db_date = l.logdate
WHERE c.db_date BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-08-10';
```

Notes:

- You want all the rows from `calendar`, so it should be the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`.
- You need valid `ON` conditions connecting the two tables.
- `BETWEEN` requires the operands to be in order, so the small one is before the `AND` and the larger after.
- `GROUP BY` seems unnecessary.

  - `COALESCE()` actually generates the `0` value.
- In a query with more than one table reference, qualify all column names.

Comment: The OP's LEFT JOIN is not correct. It is the wrong way round. `logs LEFT JOIN calendar` instead of `calendar LEFT JOIN logs`.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes . . . The answer explains this.

Answer (score 0):

Your join order is wrong, `calendar` should be on the left side as all of its rows should be included regardless of a matching row from `logs`. To transform `NULL` into `0` use `coalesce()`. And if you `GROUP BY` the date, you have to apply an aggregation function on `hoursspent`. I guess you wanted `sum()`.

```
SELECT c.db_date,
       sum(coalesce(l.hoursspent, 0)) hoursspent
       FROM calendar c
            LEFT JOIN logs l
                      ON l.logdate = c.db_date
       WHERE c.db_date BETWEEN '2018-08-10'
                               AND '2018-08-01'
       GROUP BY c.db_date;
```

Here you can also omit the `coalesce()` as MySQL's `sum()` treats `NULL` as `0` anyway.

But the sample data suggests, that you maybe don't need to `GROUP BY` at all, if there aren't more than one log entries for the same day, that is.

```
SELECT c.db_date,
       coalesce(l.hoursspent, 0) hoursspent
       FROM calendar c
            LEFT JOIN logs l
                      ON l.logdate = c.db_date
       WHERE c.db_date BETWEEN '2018-08-10'
                               AND '2018-08-01';
```

Answer (score 0):

The table having all the required rows (`Calendar`) must be on the left side of a `LEFT JOIN`, the table with missing records (`Logs`) on the right. Alternatively, you could keep the table order and instead use a `RIGHT JOIN`.

When you have more than one table in a query, it is useful to use aliases for disambiguation.

The complete `ON` clause needs a comparison.

The range specified in a `BETWEEN` condition must be in ascending order.

The `GROUP BY` clause requires you to apply an aggregate function to all non-grouping expressions in the `SELECT`-list. Here the `SUM` function is appropriate. Since the `SUM` function returns `NULL`s if there are no matching records, we apply the `COALESCE` function to convert them to `0`s.

```
SELECT
    c.db_date, COALESCE(SUM(l.hoursSpent), 0) AS hoursSpent
FROM
    Calendar c
    LEFT JOIN Logs l
        ON c.db_date = l.logDate
WHERE
    c.db_date BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-08-10'        
GROUP BY
    c.db_date;
```

See SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d28de9c/3/0